# cURL automatically replacing alternates to functional characters with underscore?

Tags: python, windows, curl, encoding

In installing and utilizing cURL (specifically `curl 7.86.0 (Windows) libcurl/7.86.0`; previously I said it was `curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1` but I was mistaken) to download .htm files in conjunction with/subordinate to a mass media-file downloading program called gallery-dl, I ran into a filenaming problem regarding how cURL deals with "weird" characters.

Basically, it seems that at least for my version or install of cURL, when I try to use some kind of alternate version of a symbol such as Big Solidus `⧸` slash instead of normal slash in the filenaming command, cURL will create the .htm file but will replace that alternate symbol with an underscore.  I know this isn't a problem with cURL interpreting the Big Solidus as a normal slash, since when I try to instead use a Fullwidth Solidus `／` slash it errors out the same way it would with a normal `/` slash.

As a simple example, try running something like `curl [url] -o C:\dir\ec\to\ry\test⧸.htm` or `curl [url] -o "test⧸.htm"` yourself.  For me, it outputs `test_.htm`.

Is there anything I can do, anything I can attach to the "weird" characters to get cURL to avoid changing them to underscores?  Or is this something version-related?

Comment: Is your question whether `curl https://www.deviantart.com/korblborp/art/354079667 -o "MJOLNIR Gen 2⧸ARC.htm"` should work (i.e. keep the `⧸` in the file name)? It does for me (using `curl 7.87.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.87.0 OpenSSL/3.0.7 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.4) libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.51.0`).

Comment: Yep, I tried that exact thing (this time like you did ditching the directory leading up to the filename and just specifying a filename) and it replaces the Big Solidus `⧸` with an underscore (using `curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1`).

Comment: I recommend to ask specifically this question. It's a great step that you've separated the problem already from `gallery-dl`, so don't confuse the reader with all those irrelevant details.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I always tend, consciously or not, to try to explain and qualify a lot of things I say to give anyone I'm talking to a fuller picture and in case any minor details end up necessary, but the gallery-dl related ones really weren't particularly.

Comment: Don't worry; your edits have IMO improved the question a lot. Regarding the problem: does your filesystem even allow for files named `test⧸.htm`, i.e. can you create them with another program than `curl`? (I don't know much about Windows file systems.)

Comment: (comment reuploaded w/ clarity edits because I couldn't edit previous version) Yes. Like I touched on in the too-long too-much-about-gallery-dl part I cut for brevity and clarity, gallery-dl was already by default replacing characters like normal forward and back slash, colon, asterisk, etc. with Big Solidus `⧸` `⧹` forward and back slash, Modifier Letter Colon `꞉`, Asterisk Operator `∗`, etc. in the webpage titles that were being assigned as part of the filenames of the images and metadata jsons it was downloading, and those replacement characters ended up in the final filenames just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so OP here, and I've since seemed to figure out a solution to this problem, although the actual nature of the solution I'm not really certain of.  It was seeming like Linux versions of cURL were not having this problem of changing characters like alternate versions of functional characters (and other characters I had since discovered mine was also changing, like Japanese characters) into underscores, while multiple Windows versions were.

My friend decided to compile a Windows build of cURL himself from the current source code available on github to run a debugger, and for some reason this version just doesn't have the changing-"odd"-characters-to-underscores problem?  It just.... doesn't have the problem at all.  You ask it to create a file with Big Solidus `⧸` or a Japanese character `あ` or anything like that and it does it just fine.

Our only guess is that it's down to a matter of slight differences created by different compilers, and the compiler used on the official Windows builds creates the problem while some other compilers don't.